# ANOVA with single degrees of freedom

Tags: anova

I was running ANOVA.

Does it make sense to use a variable with 1 degree of freedom as independent variable?

Comment: I must be missing something; any factor with two levels has 1df, and a factor with two levels is certainly suitable for an IV in ANOVA. If you're looking at one-way ANOVA, it's no different from a t-test, so you'd probably do a t-test in that specfic situation, but the ANOVA would still be valid. If this doesn't cover what you're asking about you'll need to clarify the circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, why not? For instance, you could have

- a grouping factor with two levels
- a numerical covariate ([ANCOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance))

Here is an example with both, using R:

```
> foo <- data.frame(DV=rnorm(10),IV=rnorm(10),group=rep(c("A","B"),5))
> anova(lm(DV~IV+group,foo))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: DV
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
IV         1 0.0080 0.00802  0.0084 0.9296
group      1 0.1729 0.17285  0.1809 0.6834
Residuals  7 6.6880 0.95543
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I indeed was working with a grouping factor which has 2 levels and suddenly got this doubt. Might have sounded stupid, but wanted to clarify anyway.

Comment: No problem. 1 df = 1 parameter. If you have two groups, one of them will be the reference. And the (single) parameter will estimate the difference in DV between the reference group and the other ("non-reference") group. Generally, if you have $k$ factor levels, this takes $k-1$ df.